# Xamarin forms - lottie animations

Tags: animation, xamarin.forms, lottie

I'm a beginner with Lottie, and I have a basic question:

I have a band which provides my app information about the heart rate of the user in the BPM unit.

I had downloaded from lottiefiles.com a JSON file of heart animation which shows exactly what I want - *number* BPM.

My problem is that I don't know how to set dynamically values in the animation whenever I get a new BPM value from the band.

Unfortunately, I didn't found how to do so after searching on the internet.

I suspect that maybe the function `animationView.SetValue` can help, but I don't sure exactly how.

Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: I think lottie animation is simply for showing. I dont think it can customize

Comment: Based on my research, you can not `animationView.SetValue` to set the BPM of Lottie animations,But you could use `Lable` to cover the Lottie animations when animations is stop.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the query. You want the animation to play on the rate of your user's heart BPM ?

Comment: Have you found an answer? @MrSonic